# Shortest way to replace values in nested JSON with the particular key elegantly

Tags: python, json

Imagine a nested json structure as below:

```
node = 
{
  "0" : {
    "param" : {
      "filename" : "abc",
      "delimiter" : "n"
    },
    "function" : "do something"
  },
  "1" : {
    "param" : {
      "filename" : "def",
      "delimiter" : "n"
    },
    "function" : "do something"
  },
  "2" : {
    "param" : {
      "filename" : "ghi",
      "delimiter" : "n"
    },
    "function" : "do something"
  }
}
```

I wish to replace all the filename inside the node variable into computed filename. For example I want to replace all the values of filename in "0", "1", and "2" into "example.pdf".

What is the most elegant way or shortest way to do so in Python?

Comment: `node = {new_key: v for _, v in node.items()}`

Comment: Please try to achieve it by yourself first.

Comment: Why not write a simple `for` loop? Did you try?

Comment: It is easy to get the job done ( simple for loop for example ). The key point is to write it elegantly ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about regex?

```
In [29]: import re

In [30]: json.loads(re.sub('(?<="filename": ")(.*?)(?=")', 'example.pdf',  json.dumps(node)))
Out[30]: 
{'0': {'function': 'do something',
  'param': {'delimiter': 'n', 'filename': 'example.pdf'}},
 '1': {'function': 'do something',
  'param': {'delimiter': 'n', 'filename': 'example.pdf'}},
 '2': {'function': 'do something',
  'param': {'delimiter': 'n', 'filename': 'example.pdf'}}}
```

This would not work, if you do not want to replace *every* instance.

Comment: Very creative, it also saves the need for parsing the json in the first place (+1)

Comment: @UriGoren Yes... the advantage is you can still support complex replacements with sub callbacks... but inflexible because you cannot control what is replaced :)

Comment: Creative, one line and sleek. Elegant indeed!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's elegant but I would do this:

```
for k,v in node.items():
    v["param"]["filename"]="foo{}.pdf".format(k)
```

iterate on dictionary key/values, and "navigate" to the relevant field and change it (relate it to the value of the key to illustrate)

(rebuilding the dictionary using dictionary comprehension seems overkill here)

Answer (score 0):

In case your key 'param' is not always the same, or even unknown, you can use this:

```
for k1, v1 in node.items():
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
        if 'filename' in v2:
            node[k1][k2]['filename'] = 'example.pdf'
```